# Equivalence between two probability inequalities

Tags: probability, probability-theory

I am trying to understand the following statement.

Let $F:R^n \mapsto R$ be a 1-Lipschitz function, i.e.,
$|F(x)-F(y)|\le |x-y|$, where $|\cdot|$ is the Euclidean metric.
Let $X=(X_1,\cdots,X_n)$ be a random vector whose entries are iid $N(0,1)$, the standard normal.
Then for any $\lambda > 0$,
\begin{equation} \label{eqn1}
(*) \qquad \textbf{P}(|F(X) - \textbf{E}(F(X))| \ge \lambda) \le C\exp(-c\lambda^2)
\end{equation} 
for some absolute constants $C,c>0$, is equivalent to 
the following inequality
\begin{equation}
(**) \qquad \textbf{P}(X\in A)\textbf{P}(X\not\in A_\lambda) \le C\exp(-c\lambda^2)
\end{equation}
holding for all $\lambda > 0$ and all measureable sets $A$, and
$A_\lambda$ is the $\lambda$-neighbourhood of $A$.

FYI, this is from a book of [tao's random matrix theory](https://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/02/matrix-book.pdf), especially, excericse 2.1.11.

Here is my trial. First let fix $\lambda > 0$. For convenience, let $\textbf{E}(F(X)) = 0$. Then by MVT or IVT, we have $x^* \in R^n$ such that $F(x^*) = \textbf{E}(F(X)) = 0$.
It follws from the Lipschitz property that 
$$|F(X)| = |F(X)-\textbf{E}(F(X))| \le |X-x^*|$$
Thus I got
$$ \{|X-x^*| < \lambda \} \subset \{|F(X)| < \lambda\} $$
But I am not sure how to proceed further.

Any comments or answers will be very appreciated.